# Using more worker processes than there are cores

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

[This](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#process-pools) example from PYMOTW gives an example of using `multiprocessing.Pool()` where the `processes` argument (number of worker processes) passed is twice the number of cores on the machine.

```
pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
```

(The class will otherwise default to just `cpu_count()`.)

Is there any validity to this?  What is the effect of creating more workers than there are cores?  Is there ever a case to be made for doing this, or will it perhaps impose additional overhead in the wrong direction?  I am curious as to why it would be included consistently in examples from what I consider to be a reputable site.

In an initial test, it actually seems to slow things down a bit:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 25 -r 3 'import double_cpus; double_cpus.main()'
25 loops, best of 3: 266 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 25 -r 3 'import default_cpus; default_cpus.main()'
25 loops, best of 3: 226 msec per loop
```

`double_cpus.py`:

```
import multiprocessing

def do_calculation(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i ** 2

def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(
        processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2,
        maxtasksperchild=2,
    ) as pool:
        pool.map(do_calculation, range(1000))
```

`default_cpus.py`:

```
def main():
    # `processes` will default to cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(
        maxtasksperchild=2,
    ) as pool:
        pool.map(do_calculation, range(1000))
```

Comment: For CPU bound task it doesn't make sense to create more process than available cores. For I/O bound it might make sense depending upon your hardware and OS(Whether Hardware + OS is capable of running them simultaneously).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing this can make sense if your job is not *purely* cpu-bound, but also involves some I/O.

The computation in your example is also too short for a reasonable benchmark, the overhead of just creating more processes in the first place dominates.

I modified your calculation to let it iterate over a range of 10M, while calculating an if-condition and let it take a nap in case it evaluates to `True`, which happens `n_sleep`-times.
That way a total sleep of `sleep_sec_total` can be injected into the computation.

```
# default_cpus.py
import time
import multiprocessing


def do_calculation(iterations, n_sleep, sleep_sec):
    for i in range(iterations):
        if i % (iterations / n_sleep) == 0:
            time.sleep(sleep_sec)


def main(sleep_sec_total):

    iterations = int(10e6)
    n_sleep = 100
    sleep_sec = sleep_sec_total / n_sleep
    tasks = [(iterations, n_sleep, sleep_sec)] * 20

    with multiprocessing.Pool(
        maxtasksperchild=2,
    ) as pool:
        pool.starmap(do_calculation, tasks)
```

---

```
# double_cpus.py
...

def main(sleep_sec_total):

    iterations = int(10e6)
    n_sleep = 100
    sleep_sec = sleep_sec_total / n_sleep
    tasks = [(iterations, n_sleep, sleep_sec)] * 20

    with multiprocessing.Pool(
        processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2,
        maxtasksperchild=2,
    ) as pool:
        pool.starmap(do_calculation, tasks)
```

I ran the benchmark with `sleep_sec_total=0` (purely cpu-bound) and with `sleep_sec_total=2` for both modules.

Results with `sleep_sec_total=0`:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 5 -r 3 'import default_cpus; default_cpus.main(0)'
5 loops, best of 3: 15.2 sec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 5 -r 3 'import double_cpus; double_cpus.main(0)'
5 loops, best of 3: 15.2 sec per loop
```

Given a reasonable computation-size, you'll observe close to no difference between default- and double-cpus for a purely cpu-bound task. Here it happened, that both tests had the same best-time.

Results with `sleep_sec_total=2`:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 5 -r 3 'import default_cpus; default_cpus.main(2)'
5 loops, best of 3: 20.5 sec per loop
$ python -m timeit -n 5 -r 3 'import double_cpus; double_cpus.main(2)'
5 loops, best of 3: 17.7 sec per loop
```

Now with adding 2 seconds of sleep as a dummy for I/0, the picture looks different. Using double as much processes gave a speed up of about 3 seconds compared to the default.

Comment: Up-voted for noting that it's specifically for cases where individual tasks *mix* CPU bound and I/O bound steps. If the tasks were mostly I/O bound, you'd usually just use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead, so the pool is backed by threads, not processes, removing the interprocess communication overhead. In that case, you'd also likely want more than `#cores * 2` worker threads; `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (which isn't bound by the `multiprocessing.Pool` API docs) defaults to `#cores * 5` (probably too high for spinning disk bound tasks, but find for anything else).

Answer (score 3):

If you task is I/O bound (such as waiting for a database, a network service), then making more threads than there are processors actually increases your throughput.

This is because while your thread is waiting on I/O the processor can actually do work on other threads.

If you have a CPU heavy task, then more processors will actually slow it down.